# Spring mvc jackson: log data

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have a question regardimg spring mvc and jackson mapper: every time I call a rest service passing a wrong json (empty, wron params,...) the client correctly receives an error, but there is no way to see in detail the call on server side.
Is there a way to log in a proper way this information?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Fabio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good place to start looking into the marshalling process is `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters` - that will give you a good overview of what's being executed.

As for the logging aspect, the first `catch` of the entire marshalling/unmarshalling process is `ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle`:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
   if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
      logger.trace(getReturnValueHandlingErrorMessage("Error handling return value", returnValue), ex);
   }
   throw ex;
}
```

So - enabling `TRACE` in your logging configuration here - on `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation` will give you the info you need.

Further on, another good place to catch this kind of logging output - this time with `DEBUG` instead of `TRACE` is: `DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: About the second one, I see this: `if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {logger.trace("Using resolved error view: " + exMv, ex);} if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) { logger.debug("Using resolved error view: " + exMv); }`, so which is better?