# Spring Boot Jackson - Logging

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Spring Boot, with an Angular 4 frontend.  Right now, I have an array which isn't being deserialized.  Is there a way I can turn on logging for the deserialization or Jackson part of my application?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered quite a few times:

[Spring mvc jackson: log data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635720/spring-mvc-jackson-log-data)

[Spring REST using Jackson - 400 bad request logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326976/spring-rest-using-jackson-400-bad-request-logging)

I personally prefer using Log4j with trace-level logging of package "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc"

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, posting links as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted. Or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question*. You did a little of that, but the answer could use a lot of expansion.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I am aware of "flagging as duplicate" functionality, but the rep just does not coooooome :)